Pros and cons of ESPRIT versus MUSIC
In Stoica, Spectral Analysis of Signals (4.7, page 167), the author claims the superiority of ESPRIT

The statistical accuracy of ESPRIT is similar to that of the
previously described methods: HOYW, MUSIC and Min-Norm. In fact, in
most cases, ESPRIT may provide slightly more accurate frequency
estimates than the other methods mentioned above; and this at similar
computational cost. In addition, unlike these other methods, ESPRIT
has no problem with separating the “signal roots” from the “noise
roots”, as can be seen from (4.7.12). Note that this property is
shared by the modiﬁed MUSIC method (discussed in Section 4.5);
however, in many cases ESPRIT outperforms modiﬁed MUSIC in terms of
statistical accuracy. All these considerations recommend ESPRIT as the
first choice in a frequency estimation application.

My first question is why this claim? Does "separating the signal roots from the noise roots" mean identifying the signal subspace dimension, which is usually done by classifying the eigen values of the correlation matrix? If it is the case, I don't see why ESPRIT can be better than others, e.g. MUSIC, in that issue.
Specifically, the crucial step in the ESPRIT method is identifying the signal subspace dimension $\hat{K}$ in (5) below. ESPRIT is no better than MUSIC whatsoever, IMHO.
My second question is what are the pro and cons of ESPRIT versus MUSIC? and which method do people prefer? Unlike Stoica, there are papers claiming that MUSIC is more stable and accurate than ESPRIT, e.g. this.
My last question is that as the identification of the number of source $\hat{K}$ seems crucial, is there any analysis of the impact of under/over-estimation this parameter? For example, I know that underestimating the noise subspace dimension in MUSIC can push the noise roots closer to the unit circle, but according to my simulations the closet roots still are the signal roots. On the other hand, over-estimating the signal subspace in ESPRIT distorts the results and creates spurious frequencies (again according to my simulations which might be inaccurate): ESPRIT seems much more sensible to the model order estimation error.
The three questions are related, tell me if I need to create other posts to separate the questions.
ESPRIT method
Let checking the model of the signal of $K$ sinusoid:
$$y[n] = \sum_{k=1}^{K} a_k e^{j\omega_k n} + w[n] \tag{1}$$
where $a_k$ and $w[n]$ are complex random variables. In the matrix form,
$$Y= \begin{bmatrix}e^{j\omega_1}&e^{j\omega_2}&\\e^{j2\omega_1}&e^{j2\omega_2}&\\...&...&...\\e^{jN\omega_1}&e^{jN\omega_2}&\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\...\end{bmatrix} + W = S A + W \tag{2}$$
We estimate the correlation matrix
$$R_{yy}=\mathbb{E}\left[ YY^H \right] \tag{3}$$
where $^H$ denotes the Hermitian transpose.
Take the eigen decomposition
$$R_{yy} = U \Lambda U^H \tag{4}$$
and separate the signal subspace $S$ of dimension $N\times \hat{K}$, and noise subspace $N$ of dimension $N \times (N-\hat{K})$, where $\hat{K}$ is the estimated number of sinusoid.
$$U = [S \; N] \tag{5}$$
Partition the signal subspace following the invariant rotation principle, $S_1$ and $S_2$ contain the first and the last $N-1$ rows of $S$, respectively:
$$S_1 = [I_{N-1} \; 0]S \tag{6}$$
$$S_2 = [0 \; I_{N-1}]S$$
and solve for $\phi$ from $S_1 \phi = S_2$, usually by total least square, to have:
$$\phi = (S_2^H S_2)^{-1} S_2^H S_1 \tag{7}$$
which is the (4.7.12) of the Soica book (the author use $^*$ for the Hermitian transpose).
The frequency of sinusoid can be obtained from the eigen values of $\phi$.

@Some of the pros and cons that you've identified tend to be true. Like you stated, it's important that you simulate them correctly. For starters, classic ESPRIT needs twice as many sensors than in MUSIC, but is significantly faster computation wise since its angle estimation is "one shot" via a matrix operation vs MUSIC where you need to search through the desired angles to yield the pseudospectrum.

@Envidia thanks for the comment. But we can avoid the angle search by using the root MUSIC calculating the roots via polynomial formulation of the noise subspace projection, cant we?

I was referring to classical MUSIC and yes, doing the root method with MUSIC alleviates some computational load. However, ESPRIT and its variants still require less operations to yield an accurate estimate in most cases. There is however trade-offs on calibration and the array geometry itself between MUSIC, ESPRIT, and other subspace algorithms.

@Envidia thank you. Could you give me some references about such trade-offs?

Optimum Array Processing, Part IV of Detection, Estimation, and Modulation Theory (2022), by Harry L. Van Trees.
I also realize that this is a more general question on these algorithms, which are used in other areas besides array processing (the source provided), so keep that in mind as YMMV. The trade-offs are in reference to processing receive signals in antenna arrays, but with a little work you can distill them down to other types of signal sources.

This language, admittedly, was pretty confusing to me the first time I went through it as well. I'm not 100% sure my interpretation is correct, however, I will attempt to do my best.
ESPRIT is more accurate because it does not perform a grid search to solve for the roots of a polynomial, it instead directly estimates the first $K$ signals, which are considered the signal subspace. MUSIC on the other hand solves for
\begin{equation}
a^{H}(\omega)\mathbf{G}\mathbf{G}^{H}a(\omega) = 0
\end{equation}
of which the true frequency values are the only solutions (where $\mathbf{G}$ is a matrix where the columns are the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues in the noise subspace). This requires a grid search, that for practical applications needs to be discretized, thus limiting the resolution and accuracy (unless the frequencies/DOAs are known ahead of time, which seems to be the case in that paper you provided). ESPRIT doesn't perform this grid search, but instead directly estimates the frequencies via a least-squares framework.
The pros of ESPRIT are that it directly estimates the frequencies, as previously discussed, thus reducing the statistical ambiguity in the frequency estimates compared to MUSIC. The main con of ESPRIT that I've seen is that, in some papers, I've seen the claim that closely spaced sources can degrade the accuracy of ESPRIT (don't recall as to why, but my guess is that the rotational invariance assumption is violated). MUSIC on the other hand is nice because it produces a pseudo-spectrum (PSD), so it can be used for that purpose as well, and in certain cases can perform better than ESPRIT as previously mentioned.
Both ESPRIT and MUSIC will suffer from model order mismatch. This is the primary disadvantage of any parametric spectral estimator (temporal or spatial).

For example, I know that underestimating the noise subspace dimension in MUSIC can push the noise roots closer to the unit circle, but according to my simulations the closet roots still are the signal roots. On the other hand, over-estimating the signal subspace in ESPRIT distorts the results and creates spurious frequencies (again according to my simulations which might be inaccurate): ESPRIT seems much more sensible to the model order estimation error.

The closest roots may still be the signal roots, but this is only guaranteed asymptotically, so in finite dimensional applications, this is not guaranteed (see the end of 4.4 in the Stoica and Moses book). Your assessment of ESPRIT is also correct I would say, but again, the idea of parametric models is that we have some a priori knowledge of what we are estimating. In the case of a model match, ESPRIT is usually going to perform better (for unknown DOAs).
One variant of MUSIC that I much prefer over MUSIC is known as Eigenvector. MUSIC whitens the clutter subspace, which can lead to very spurious results in model mismatch. Eigenvector doesn't whiten the clutter subspace, and therefore can mitigate spurious estimates in some cases and also has better noise spectrum shaping in the cases where it's being used as a pseudo-spectra.
One thing I disagree with on the Stoica and Moses book is the computational complexity comparisons of ESPRIT and MUSIC. If you actually solve spectral MUSIC via the full polynomial at each frequency $\omega$, then yes, it would be quite expensive. However, with some algebraic manipulation, Spectral MUSIC, ie
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{a^{H}(\omega)\mathbf{G}\mathbf{G}^{H}a(\omega)}
\end{equation}
can be computed for a uniform discretized grid search via an FFT. I am not aware of any ability to do this for ESPRIT (since it doesn't involve a grid search).

Thank you for the great answer. About "The pros of ESPRIT are that it directly estimates the frequencies", we can do the same thing with Root MUSIC (applicable for both MUSIC and EV), can't we?

It seems that you know a lot about the subspace methods. Do you know which library I can use to implement the eigen decomposition of autocovariance matrix? I am using the SVD functions of Intel MKL but they are not fast enough.

@Rokai if you are interested in only the dominant frequencies and not a pseudo-spectrum, yes you can. However, you can see in this answer https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/95041/computing-modern-spectral-estimation-techniques-with-ffts/95043#95043 that you can compute the whole pseudo-spectrum with an FFT. As for a library, I'm not sure. Eigendecompositions are $\mathcal{O}(N^{3})$. Matlab I think uses Eigen, but I don't know if that will be faster or not.
