Computing modern spectral estimation techniques with FFTs
This question is a follow-up to this Pisarenko Harmonic Decomposition question. In the answer and comments gathered there, it appears that instead of computing the Pisarenko pseudo-spectrum using the (steering vector * min. eigvec) product in
$S_{Pisarenko}(\omega) = \dfrac{1}{|e^H(\omega)v_{min}|^2}$
for a relevant set of $\omega$-s where $v_{min}$ is the eigenvector of the smallest-modulus eigenvalue of the signal autocorrelation matrix $R \in \mathbb{C}^{(M+1) \times (M+1)}$ with $M$ the number of pure sine waves in the signal getting decomposed, one can directly compute the FFT (i.e. the DFT) of the right-side zero-padded $v_{min}$. Why is that true? Why is that true for that specific padding choice? Does this only work for Pisarenko's case, i.e. when there's a single noise eigenvalue/eigenvector, or does that work with multiple noise eigenvalues (i.e. MUSIC generalization) as well?
Using the definition of the DFT, this possibility leads to the following equivalence:
$S_{Pisarenko}(\omega) = \dfrac{1}{|e^H(\omega)v_{min}|^2} = \dfrac{1}{|\sum_i v_{min_i} e^{-j2\pi \frac{p(\omega)}{N}i}|^2} $ with $N$ the number of elements in the steering vector $e(\omega) = [1~e^{j\omega}~ ... ~ e^{j(N-1)\omega}]$. In the DFT term, perhaps the $p(\omega)$ looks weird. The DFT sum has $M+1$ non-zero elements, since $v_{min} \in \mathbb{C}^{M+1}$.
These quantities (with the $\frac{1}{|.|^2}$ missing to get to the actual pseudo-spectrum) are computed in the following code lines in the linked PHD question:
pseudo_spect = np.squeeze(np.matmul(np.conjugate(steervec), eig_vec[:,np.newaxis]))

# use FFT of zero-padded eigvec for alternative proposed by Baddioes
zpad_eigvec = np.pad(eig_vec, pad_width=(0, pseudo_spect.shape[0] - eig_vec.shape[0]))
pseudo_spect_fft = np.fft.fft(zpad_eigvec)


The idea that this can be done is based on the idea that the Fourier transform is an orthobasis expansion. See more details on this answer. The idea that we pull from this though is that the Fourier transform produces the Fourier coefficients from a series of inner products. The definition of an inner product is
\begin{equation}
\langle x(t),y(t) \rangle = \int x(t)\bar{y}(t)dt
\end{equation}
where $\left\{ \bar{\cdot}\right\}$ is the conjugate. The Fourier transform wishes to find the inner product between signal $x(t)$ and complex exponential at frequency $\omega$, which is $e^{j\omega t}$. Plugging this back in, we get
\begin{equation}
\langle x(t),y(t) \rangle = \int x(t)e^{-j\omega t}dt
\end{equation}
which is the Fourier transform.
In vector notation, an inner product is a row vector multiplied by a column vector
\begin{equation}
\alpha = \underline{a}^{H}\underline{b}
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align}
\underline{a} &= \begin{bmatrix} a(0) & \cdots & a(N-1) \end{bmatrix}^{T} \\
\underline{b} &= \begin{bmatrix} b(0) & \cdots & b(N-1) \end{bmatrix}^{T} 
\end{align}
So, taking the inner product of $x(t)$ with a steering vector
\begin{equation}
a(\omega) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & e^{j\omega} & \cdots & e^{j\omega(n-1)}\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
is equivalent to finding the FFT at frequency $\omega$. This is what
\begin{equation}
e^{H}(\omega)v_{min}
\end{equation}
represents!
Now, in terms of zero-padding or not, that is likely not going to affect the magnitude, and we take the magnitude squared, so I don't think this would matter too much, you could do padding as long as it aligns with the forward FFT.

for Pisarenko's case i.e. single noise eigenvalue/eigenvector only or does that work with multiple noise eigenvalues (=MUSIC generalization) as well

It does work for MUSIC and other spectral estimation methods as well. Note, the definition of MUSIC
\begin{equation}
S_{music}(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sigma_{0}^{-2}\sum_{k}\left\lvert a^{H}(\omega)g(k)\right\rvert^{2}}
\end{equation}
This looks very similar to a Welch's method computed over all the eigenvectors, however, it goes even further than that! We can rewrite MUSIC as
\begin{align}
S_{music}(\omega) &= \frac{1}{\sigma_{0}^{-2}\sum_{k}\left\lvert a^{H}(\omega)g(k)\right\rvert^{2}} \\ &= \frac{1}{\sigma_{0}^{-2}\sum_{k} a^{H}(\omega)g(k)g^{H}(k)a(\omega)} \\ &= \frac{1}{\sigma_{0}^{-2}a^{H}(\omega)\left[\sum_{k} g(k)g^{H}(k)\right]a(\omega)}
\end{align}
If we let the matrix $\mathbf{U} = \sum_{k} g(k)g^{H}(k)$, we get
\begin{equation}
S_{music}(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sigma_{0}^{-2}a^{H}(\omega)\mathbf{U}a(\omega)}
\end{equation}
Explicitly writing out the computation for a row vector multiplied by a matrix multiplied by a column vector is
\begin{equation}
a^{H}\mathbf{B}c = \sum_{k=0}^{M-1}\sum_{l=0}^{N-1}\mathbf{B}(k,l)a(k)c(l)
\end{equation}
In the case of $a^{H}(\omega)\mathbf{U}a(\omega)$, we have $M=N$ and $c$ is the steering vector, with $a$ being its conjugate. So, plugging in we get
\begin{align}
a^{H}(\omega)\mathbf{U}a(\omega) &= \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\sum_{l=0}^{N-1}\mathbf{U}(k,l)e^{-j\omega k}e^{j\omega l} \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\sum_{l=0}^{N-1}\mathbf{U}(k,l)e^{-j\omega (k-l)}
\end{align}
Plugging in $k-l=\alpha$, we get
\begin{align}
a^{H}(\omega)\mathbf{U}a(\omega) &= \sum_{\alpha}\sum_{k-l=\alpha}\mathbf{U}(k,l)e^{-j\omega \alpha} \\ & = \sum_{\alpha=-N+1}^{N-1}e^{-j\omega \alpha}\sum_{k-l=\alpha}\mathbf{U}(k,l) \\ &= e^{j\omega(N-1)}\sum_{\gamma=0}^{2N-1}b\left(\gamma-(N-1)\right)e^{-j\omega\gamma}
\end{align}
where
\begin{equation}
b(\alpha) = \sum_{k-l=\alpha}\mathbf{U}(k,l)
\end{equation}
This is a lot of math, but basically what this equates to is a presum along the diagonals of $\mathbf{U}$, so that if $\mathbf{U}\in \mathbb{C}^{M\text{x}M}$, then $b\in\mathbb{C}^{2M-1\text{x}1}$. We then take an FFT of $b$ and take the magnitude, and this is our spectral estimate.
This is very powerful as we can compute a large number of spectral estimation techniques this way. For example
\begin{align}
S_{Per}(\omega) &= a^{H}(\omega)\mathbf{R}a(\omega) \\ S_{Capon}(\omega) &= \frac{1}{a^{H}(\omega)\mathbf{R}^{-1}a(\omega)} \\ S_{ARLP}(\omega) &= \frac{1}{a^{H}(\omega)\mathbf{\chi}a(\omega)} \\ S_{EV/MUSIC}(\omega) &= \frac{1}{a^{H}(\omega)\mathbf{U}_{EV/MUSIC}a(\omega)}
\end{align}
where
\begin{equation}
\chi = \alpha\alpha^{H}
\end{equation}
where $\alpha$ is the AR parameters, and
\begin{align}
\mathbf{U}_{MUSIC} &= \sigma_{0}^{-2}\sum_{n=p+1}^{N}v(k)v^{H}(k) \\ \mathbf{U}_{EV} &= \sum_{n=p+1}^{N}\frac{1}{\lambda_{k}}v(k)v^{H}(k)
\end{align}
As you note, the term $p(\omega)$ is necessary because the steering vector may not be defined for uniform sampling (or a ULA). These methods work under the assumption of a uniform framework, although they could be extended to a non-uniform framework via an NUDFT I'm sure. Another interesting problem is how to find the matrix $\mathbf{U}$ in each of the cases. These methods typically first require the computation of $\mathbf{R}$, the covariance matrix, which is done by matrix multiplication, which is $\mathcal{O}\left(N^{2}\right)$. Additionally, typical estimates of $\mathbf{R}$ are positive semi- definite, and the inversion is $\mathcal{O}\left(N^{3}\right)$. This means that all eigenvalues are greater than or equal to 0. If an eigenvalue is 0, this produces a spectral null, which is undesirable. Therefore, it is best to use a toeplitz, biased estimate of the covariance matrix since it is positive definite, meaning all eigenvalues are strictly greater than 0. The biased estimate of the covariance matrix can be computed from the autocorrelation sequence, defined as
\begin{equation}
r[k] = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x^{*}[n]x[n-k]
\end{equation}
The correlation matrix is then populated with appropriate values of $r[k]$. For example, the main diagonal (0th diagonal) is populated with $r(0)$. The first diagonal (first off diagonal) is populated with $r(1)$. The $-1$th digaonal (first off diagonal in other direction) is populated with $r(-1)$, and so on. Since the ACS is computed via FFT, the covariance matrix can be computed in $\mathcal{O}\left(N\log N\right)$, and since it is Hermitian and Toeplitz, the inverse is computed in $\mathcal{O}\left(N^{2}\right)$. Additionally, using this method provides equivalence between the periodogram and correlogram, and connects to all other spectral estimates (see Stoica and Moses).
Hope this helps!

I'll process this a bit with pen & paper, along with AlexTP's answer, thanks a lot. I think there is a small typo in your final autocorrelation sequence definition, where you sum over $n$ while using the time index $t$ inside the sum.

For $$V(\omega) := v^H e(\omega)=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}v_n^*e^{jn\omega},$$
if you choose to evaluate the $V(\omega)$ at $\omega=k\frac{2\pi}{N}$
$$V(k)=v^H e(k\frac{2\pi}{N})=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}v_n^*e^{jnk\frac{2\pi}{N}},$$
the set of $V(k)$ for $k=0~...~(N-1)$ is the DFT of $v^H$ by definition.
Therefore DFT can be use to evaluate the pseudospectrum and FFT is an efficient way to do so.
This is true for any method using the projection of the steering vector into a subspace of eigenvectors, as for subspace $G=[v_1 ~...~ v_m]$:
$$S(\omega) = \frac{1}{|e^H(\omega)G|^2}=\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^m|e^H(\omega)v_i|^2}=\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^m|v_i^H e(\omega)|^2}$$
The FFT is computed for each eigenvectors whose squared magnitudes are then summed.
